# preventDefault() not working on SELECT elements in Firefox 9.0.1

Tags: jquery, events, firefox, event-handling, preventdefault

I realise there are other questions on preventDefault() not working with Firefox, but they did not help me.

I've got three SELECT lists, and all I want is to navigate between them using the arrow keys *without changing any values*. The code works great in Chrome, but in Firefox it moves focus and then changes the value on the element just moved to.

http://jsbin.com/ofitif/3/edit

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
  $('.myinput').keydown(function (evt) { onkeydown(evt); });
  $('.myinput:first').focus(); 
}); 

function onkeydown(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  console.log(evt.which);
  if(evt.which == 39) {
    $(document.activeElement).next().focus();
  }
  else if(evt.which == 37) {
    $(document.activeElement).prev().focus();
  }             
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="inputs">
    <select class="myinput">
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
    </select>
    <select class="myinput">
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
    </select>
    <select class="myinput">
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Andrew Whitaker. I'll make sure to include the code myself next time.

Answer (score 1):

`nsListControlFrame::KeyPress` in http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/layout/forms/nsListControlFrame.cpp doesn't seem to check whether the default action was prevented.  File a bug?

Comment: It turns out that this is [Bug 291082](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=291082) and it's almost 7 years old...

Answer (score 1):

according to your requirement try passing value for prevent default..it will be something like below..

```
evt.preventDefault ? evt.preventDefault() : evt.returnValue = false;
```

it worked for me plz try it.......

Answer (score 0):

Return `false` from your `keydown` handler:

```
$('.myinput').keydown(function (evt) { onkeydown(evt); return false; });
```

Comment: Thanks @techfoobar, but that doesn't seem to make it work on Firefox.