# Restrict option in select element

Tags: javascript, html, select

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Prevent select dropdown from opening in FireFox and Opera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11603453/prevent-select-dropdown-from-opening-in-firefox-and-opera)

I have a select tag in html file, what i want is to open my own table on clicking this Select tag. but with this option window of Select tag also opens which i dont want to.
 Is there any way so that option will not open in SELECT tag?

Comment: I can not use Jquery... But is this possible in YUI..

Comment: You want to use the `select` tag without opening it?

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT` drop down menu is opened right after you trigger `mousedown` event. To prevent it from opening, you must block the event on `mousedown` so that it won't trigger any further event. This is the example:

```
function test() {
  // do something here
  return false;
}
```

with HTML

```
<select onmousedown="test();"><!-- options here --></select>
```

**OR**

```
function test() {
  // do something here
}
```

with HTML

```
<select onmousedown="test(); return false;"><!-- options here --></select>
```

The difference is with the 1st method, you can't call anymore function in the `mousedown` event on the `SELECT` tag. But you can do it with the 2nd method right before `return false;`